# Why I can't use += to change a local variable of a function in the sub-function in it?

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter

## Enviroment:

Python 3.10.3, VSCode, Windows 11

## Describing:

I write a program with tkinter by Python.

```py
def examination():
    exam = Frame()
    exam.pack()
    quesinfo = []
    quesnumb = 0

    def next():
        is_right.forget()
        nextques.forget()
        okayques.grid(column=5, row=2, columnspan=2)
        quesnumb += 1
        quesinfo.append(core())
        question.set(quesinfo[quesnumb][0])
```

This is just a part of my code, but the problem is here. When I run the program, the interpreter says:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\${MyName}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\Python\Usable Programs\Auto Maths Questions UI\Main.py", line 102, in next
    quesnumb = quesnumb + 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'quesnumb' referenced before assignment
```

You know, `quesnumb` is a local variable, so I can't use `global` to declare it.
But, that's joking! Look at to the source code again:

```py
quesinfo.append(core())
question.set(quesinfo[quesnumb][0])
```

It's correct, But why `quesnumb += 1` is not?

## Fixing and Debugging

I tried my best to fix it.
For testing and dubugging, I replaced `quesnumb += 1` to `quesnumb = 1`. It ran successfully!
I think, maybe `quesnumb` can just reference or assignment? So I replaced it to `quesnumb = quesnumb + 1`.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\${MyName}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\Python\Usable Programs\Auto Maths Questions UI\Main.py", line 102, in next
    quesnumb = quesnumb + 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'quesnumb' referenced before assignment
```

Uh-huh...
That's a real Unexpect Wrong...

I must get the answer in time, because I'll use this program on a competition at Sunday (Mar. 27). Winning the competition is all depends on this program. Could you help me to check the problem and find the root cause? Thanks so much!

Comment: It looks like the first code snippet is wrongly intended. You declare a function inside a function.

Comment: variable in a function are read-only to inner functions. reading, re-defining (albeit as one local to the inner function) are okay. writing is a no

Comment: @Damiaan that's intended (no pun intended), to be defined as a sub-function

Comment: You learn something everyday!

Comment: Variable `quesnumb` is not `global`. It is `nonlocal` so use that keyword